# How to nest stored procedures that use one stream in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following architecture:

- Main stored procedure `main_sproc`
- Nested stored procedure `nested_sproc`

The task we have is processing data from a `stream` in Snowflake but have to do it from a nested approach.

Thus this would be the code:

```sql
create or replace procedure nested_sproc()
returns varchar
language sql
as
begin
  begin transaction;

  insert into table1
  select * from stream; -- it will be more complex than this and multiple statements

  commit;
end;


create or replace procedure main_sproc()
returns varchar
language sql
as
begin
  begin transaction;

  insert into table1
  select * from stream; -- it will be more complex than this and multiple statements

  call nested_sproc();

  commit;
end;
```

When I try to run `call main_sproc()` I notice that the first statements goes through but when it reaches `call nested_sproc()` the transaction is blocked. I guess it's because I have in both procedures a `begin transaction` and `commit` but without them I get an error stating that I need to define the scope of the transaction. I need to deploy this final procedure on a task that runs on a schedule but without having to merge the queries from both procedures and the ability to still process the current data inside the stream.

Is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: Given that the documentation explicitly states you can call a SP within a transaction, I doubt that’s the problem. Can you update your question with the actual error message and the code for your SP, if it’s not precisely what you have in question.

Comment: With the current setup (having `begin transaction` and `commit` in both sprocs) I don't get an error. It just hangs...when I look in the query history I see two running queries. `call main_sproc()` has status `Running` and `call nested_sproc()` has status `Blocked`. It seems that each sproc is waiting for the other one to finish. I only get an error if I remove the `begin transaction` and `commit` from the `nested_sproc()`. I guess it would work if I remove it from both sprocs but then by the time the 2nd DML statement hits the stream,it will be empty cause the 1st one would have autocommited.

Comment: Sorry - just realised what you are doing. You can't have two processes reading the same stream simultaneously as the running a DML command is altering that stream - so your outer SP is selecting from the stream and will lock it until the outer SP transaction completes. You'll need to find another approach to achieve your end result e.g. in the outer SP write the stream to a table and use that table in the inner SP

Comment: that's actually a great idea

Comment: If you use a temporary table it should be available when either SP is running (as they will be part of the same session) and then will get automatically dropped when the session ends - as long as you don't need this data outside of the 2 SPs this might be more convenient as you have less maintenance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per the comments by @NickW, you can't have two processes reading the same stream simultaneously as the running a DML command is altering that stream - so your outer SP is selecting from the stream and will lock it until the outer SP transaction completes. You'll need to find another approach to achieve your end result e.g. in the outer SP write the stream to a table and use that table in the inner SP. If you use a temporary table it should be available when either SP is running (as they will be part of the same session) and then will get automatically dropped when the session ends - as long as you don't need this data outside of the 2 SPs this might be more convenient as you have less maintenance.

Comment: just wondering why you've repeated all the information previously given related to this question and added no new information of your own? What was the point of you adding this answer?

Comment: @NickW so that the question doesn't remain unanswered. This helps to keep the tag clean. I sometimes do this when a question is answered in comments and there is no posted "answer", but I ensure that I credit the person who commented. Please feel free to post your own answer and I will delete mine :)

Comment: @NickW does my explanation make sense ?

Comment: @NickW I've tried to address in my comment above, the points that you raised. I would appreciate your feedback. Thanks :)

Comment: @NickW...can you post the comment as an answer so I can mark it?